# Find $(x,y)$ if $6^x+2^y+2=k^2$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Q. Supposing $6^x+2^y+2$ is a perfect square, find $(x,y)$ where we assume $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers.

I tried modulo $3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10$. But I don't know how to get answer.

Please give me some hint.

Answer (score 2):

If $2$ divides both sides, then so does $4$. (Why?)

Hence, $3^x2^{x-1}+2^{y-1}+1$ must be even. That is, $3^x2^{x-1}+2^{y-1}$ must be odd. Can you find out when and how this is possible?

PS/Edit: Note that the above is only when both $x,y$ are greater than or equal to $1$. Make sure you don't forget to see what happens when either (or both) are zero.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you I finally get (x,y)=(0,0), (1,0), (1,3). Is it right?

Comment: Seems right to me @Matholic

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, you tried modulo 4 ? Anyways here are some hints.

Note that if $x,y$ are greater than $1$, then LHS is $2 \mod 4$ ,not possible since squares are $0$ or $ 1 \mod 4$.

Hence, we get  cases , either $x=0$ or $x=1$ or $y=0$ or $y=1$ .

Proceed with each case separately.

the $x=0$ case can be handled with $\mod 3$ ,the  $x=1$ case  can also  be handled with $\mod 3$, the $y=0$ case can also be handled with $\mod 3$.

when $y=1$ , we get $6^x=k^2-4$ , try factoring the RHS and factor the LHS too , then use GCD.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you I finally get (x,y)=(0,0), (1,0), (1,3). Is it right?

Comment: (1,1) satisfies too ..i guess

Comment: @Shubhangi (1,1) gives 10, which is not a perfect square.

Comment: oh yes.. thanks @AryanSonwatikar